# jqPlot seems to be invisible

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, jstree, jqplot

my jqPlot works fine as long as it is placed in an own html file. If I embed it in a div of another html file, it stops working.

Works fine (own html file)

```
<div class="generic-container-no-background">
    <div id="chart1" style="width:80%; height:80%"></div>
</div>
```

Doesn't work any more (embedded in another html file)

```
<div class="generic-container-no-background collapse" id="collapseMembersView">         
   <div id="chart1" style="width:80%; height:80%"></div>
</div>
```

The code for the chart looks like:

```
 $(function() {
        var line1 = [['Nissan', 4],['Porche', 6],['Acura', 2],['Aston Martin', 5],['Rolls Royce', 6]];

        $('#chart1').jqplot([line1], {
            title:'Bar Chart with Varying Colors',
            seriesColors:['#85802b', '#00749F', '#73C774', '#C7754C', '#00749F'],
            seriesDefaults:{
                renderer:$.jqplot.BarRenderer,
                rendererOptions: {
                    // Set the varyBarColor option to true to use different colors for each bar.
                    // The default series colors are used.
                    varyBarColor: true
                }
            },
            axes:{
                xaxis:{
                    renderer: $.jqplot.CategoryAxisRenderer
                }
            }
        });
});
```

The chart is not shown any more - neither background, nor the bars. It seems to be invisible. Can anyone suggest a solution? Thank you very much.

I am not sure if it is a helpful information, but in that another html file I also use the an jsTree object and angular.

Comment: any console errors?

Comment: Did you include the js file in the other html file?

Comment: yes, the js file is properly included. There are no console errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If found the problem! I have an upper div with angular data-toggle="collapse".

```
<div class="ts-sticker-panel" data-toggle="collapse"
                data-target="#collapseMembersView" ...>
```

I removed the collapse class - now the chart is shown.

```
<div class="generic-container-no-background" id="collapseMembersView">         
   <div id="chart1" style="width:80%; height:80%"></div>
</div>
```

But still would like to now if the jqPlot can work in combination with the angular data-toggle. Does anyone have an idea?